# Unable to get values of checkboxes with jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to get all selected checkbox values with JavaScript, but I have not been able to accomplish it until now. This is what I have tried. What am I doing wrong?

JS:

```
var femaleMatches = [];
$(".selectFemaleService:checked").each(function() {
    console.log('found a female');
    femaleMatches.push(this.value);
});
```

PHP:

```
echo "<div class='checkbox'><label><input id='selectFemaleServices' name='selectFemaleServices' type='checkbox' value='$id'>$description</label></div>";
```

Comment: You have set `id` mate, not `class`, so it should be `#selectFemaleService:checked`. Also the `id` seems to be in plural.

Comment: How many checkboxes does your code output? If it's more than one then you're duplicating IDs which is a no-no.

Comment: there is mistake in selecter use # for id

Comment: I also tried it with #, but don't get an output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the *input name* instead of the *class* to select it using jQuery

```
$("input[name='selectFemaleServices']:checked").each(function() {
```

Comment: a small correction mate, the `name` is `selectFemaleServices`. Note the plural :)

Comment: Also you need to mix your quotes up, what you have now will give you a syntax error.

Comment: As Harry mentioned, my name and selector did not match! That was the problem!

Comment: Thanks @Harry & RoryMcCrossan, my bad !

Answer (score 4):

Your jQuery is selecting by `class`, yet your checkboxes have an `id`. If there are multiple checkboxes you should change the `id` to `class` so you don't end up with duplicates.

```
echo "<div class='checkbox'>" 
        . "<label>"
            . "<input class='selectFemaleServices' name='selectFemaleServices' type='checkbox' value='$id'>$description"
        . "</label>"
    . "</div>";
```

Comment: If you run that in PHP you will get 0 as the result

Comment: @d4rkpr1nc3 thanks, forgot what the concatenation char was in PHP.

Comment: Cool! +1 for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help, the included fiddle shows how it does populate the array. You might need to change the way in which it is adding / or add remove functionality, but this will get you the value in the array

```
var femaleMatches = [];
$(".selectFemaleService").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        console.log('found a female');
        femaleMatches.push($(this).val()); 
        console.log(femaleMatches);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8uZ3e/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    var femaleMatches = [];
    $(".selectFemaleService").each(function() {
        if(this.checked){
        console.log('found a female');
        femaleMatches.push(this.value);
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JPvwJ/